# POST wrong in javascript

Tags: javascript

I´m making a recover password page and I have to POST some xml information to an specific API.

My complete code is this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<title> - Renew Password</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?    
family=Open+Sans:400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic" />


  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      background: #F2F2F2; <!--url(http://peoplepowerco.com/img/email/bgBlueLg.png)--> 
      no-repeat;
      background-size: 100%;
      color: #333;
      text-shadow: #fff 0px 1px 0px;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    #header {
      width: 100%;
      height: 45px;
      background: #1CC0B1 url(http://wisemx.com.mx/img/logo.png) no-repeat;
      background-size: 200px 45px;
    }

    #logo {
      width: 0px;
      height: 0px;
    }

    h1 {
      color: #1CC0B1;
      text-shadow: #000 0px 0px 0px;
    }

    .container {
      width: 500px;
      margin: 0px auto;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .box {
      background: #E0E0E0;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#E9E9E9), 
      to(#D7D7D7));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E9E9E9, #D7D7D7);
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px #B2B3B5;
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px #B2B3B5;
      -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px #B2B3B5;
      -khtml-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px #B2B3B5;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px #B2B3B5;
      -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
      -o-border-radius: 18px;
      -khtml-border-radius: 18px;
      border-radius: 18px;
      behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
      border: solid 3px #FFFFFF;
    }

    label {
      font-size: 18px;
    }

    input {
      font-size: 18px;
    }

    input.button-primary { 
      display: inline-block; 
      padding: 8px 20px 10px; 
      text-decoration: none; 
      font-weight: bold; 
      -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
      border-radius: 10px; 
      behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
      background-color: #f1f1f2;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f1f1f2), 
            to(#acacae)); 
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f1f1f2,  #acacae); 
      color: #333;
      text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0 #fff, #000 1px 1px 5px;
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0 #fff, #000 1px 1px 5px;
      -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0 #fff, #000 1px 1px 5px;
      -khtml-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0 #fff, #000 1px 1px 5px;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0 #fff, #000 1px 1px 5px;
      border: none; 
      font-size: 18px;
      font-family: FuturaHv, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    input.button-primary:hover  { 
      background-color: #026eb2;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#98d7fe), 
          to(#026eb2)); 
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #98d7fe,  #026eb2); 
      color: #ffffff;
      text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #333333;
    }

    input.button-primary:active { 
      background-color: #004b7b;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#026eb2), 
          to(#004b7b)); 
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #026eb2,  #004b7b); 
      color: #cccccc;
      text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #000000;
    }

    input.button-primary:disabled   { 
      background-color: #f1f1f2;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f1f1f2), 
        to(#acacae)); 
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f1f1f2,  #acacae); 
      color: #999;
      text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0 #fff;
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0 #fff;
      -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0 #fff;
      -khtml-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0 #fff;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0 #fff;
      border: none; 
    }
  </style>


<script>
    function submitForm()
    {

    var res = document.URL.split("=");

    res[1] = 
                   "XOXc4PKYCIMOMPYstCFZeCGhaeuYbqZZTvl6PwaOOb6rpu2npNhXT2Vr7Js6J2UX";

    var request = 
                "http://developer.peoplepowerco.com/espapi/rest/user/"+res[1];

         var frm = document.forms[0];
         var pwdElement = frm.elements["pwd"]
         var pwdConfirmElement = frm.elements["pwdConfirm"]

             if (pwdElement.value.length < 6)
             {
                    alert('La contraseña debe ser de al menos 6 
                              caracteres de largo');
             }
         else if (pwdElement.value == pwdConfirmElement.value)
         {

            var user= "<request><user><password>" + pwdElement.value + 
                        "</password></user></request>";

            alert('DENTRO     ' + request + '     ' + user);

            $.ajax({
            url:request,
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"text/xml",
            data: user,
            async: false,
            success:
                function(){
                    alert("Datos modificados exitosamente");
                    //window.location.href= "inicio.html";  
                },
            error:
                function( data, status, byKey ){
                    alert("Contraseña no modificada, intente 
                               otra vez");
                },
            cache:false
        });

         alert("FUERA!");

             var sbmButtom = frm.elements["submitButton"];
             sbmButtom.disable=true;
             frm.submit();   
         }   
         else
         {
            alert("Las contraseñas no coinciden. Favor de corregirlo e 
        intentar otra vez.")         
         }
    }
   </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="logo"></div>

  <div class="container">
   <br clear="all">
   <form name="renewPassword" method="post" action="/espapi/rest/newPassword"     
    onsubmit="return false">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="tVzRl9fNE2ZAOt6yDx6frFCbsFQt2gyuKWn3wWkJ-           
           9oTrmiyprssDMWaEDEXylUk"/>

     <h1>Escriba su nueva contraseña</h1>
    <div class="box">
    <p>
      <label for="pwd">Nueva contraseña:</label><br>
      <input id="pwd" name="pwd" type="password" value="">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="pwdConfirm">Confirmar contraseña:</label><br>
      <input id="pwdConfirm" name="pwdConfirm" type="password" value="">
    </p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <p>
    <input type="button" name="submitButton" onclick="javascript:submitForm()"       
   value="Cambiar contraseña" class="button-primary">
  </p>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I don´t know what's wrong because when I write a smaller password or the passwords aren't the same; it showed me the alerts that I want but when everything is fine nothing happen. Could you help me??

Comment: Missing reference to `jQuery` ??

Comment: Developer's console would help.

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax()` is a `jQuery` feature. You have reference the `jQuery` library if you want to use that feature.
For example, you can add CDN reference to `jQuery` or download a copy to your server and reference it.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I add the reference and that just made all my code stop working. What could that be??

Comment: Wont be able to guess what exactly `my code stop working` means. you will have to update your question with what error you have.